# Return unicode string from python via ajax

Tags: python, ajax, unicode

I have a small webapp that runs Python on the server side and javascript (jQuery) on the client side.
Now upon a certain request my Python script returns a unicode string and the client is supposed to put that string inside a div in the browser. However i get a unicode encode error from Python.

If i run the script from the shell (bash on debian linux) teh script runs fine and prints the unicode string.

Any ideas ?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

This is the print statement that causes the error:

```
print u'öäü°'
```

This is the error message i get:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 34-36: ordinal not in range(128)

However i only get that message when calling the script via ajax ( $('#somediv').load('myscript.py'); )

Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

If the python interpreter can't determine the encoding of `sys.stdout` ascii is used as a fallback however the characters in the string are not part of ascii, therefore a `UnicodeEncodeError` exception is raised.

A solution would be to encode the string yourself using something like `.encode(sys.stdout.encoding or "utf-8")`. This way utf-8 is used as a fallback instead of ascii.